# Python Idle help pager

Tags: python, python-idle

From the Python Idle shell, the output from the `help()` command is not paged. Is there any way to achieve this?

As a workaround I've tried to use `pydoc.pager()` but with no success. The following works in a normal Python shell started from the terminal but not in the Python Idle shell.

```
import pydoc

def ihelp(thing):
    '''Render text documentation, given an object or a path to an object, and
    sends the resulting text to a pager.'''

    pydoc.pager(pydoc.render_doc(thing))
```

**Edit:** Just to avoid misunderstandings. The `ihelp()` functions gets the help text both in a terminal Python shell and in the IDLE shell. Paging only works in the terminal shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works in delivering help output but not in paging it.  The pager executes in the user code run process and does not know how to interact with an IDLE shell in a separate gui process.  I don't believe you can change this.

To address this issue, IDLE has a new feature, starting with 3.6.7 and 3.7.1 (the release candidates are available now, the final releases will be out in a week or so).  IDLE squeezes 'long' output to a button.  (By default, 'long' is 50 lines, but user can modify this.  Shorted output can be squeezed by right-clicking on it.)

```
>>> help(int)
[ Squeezed text (241 lines) ]  # <== tkinter button
>>>
```

You can expand the text in place, with a double click, or into the clipboard or a separate non-modal view window, with a right click.  A separate window lets one scroll or page up and down in the help entry while writing a statement in the Shell.

Comment: Yes, my `ihelp()` functions delivers help output both in a terminal shell and in the IDLE shell. I've edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: The new feature in the seems very nice. I will check it out.